# ambiguous use of header file

Tags: ros, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use a package::header as usual like this:

```
void callbackBB(package_msgs::header msgs_x)
{
}
```

but the compiler indicates the headerfile is ambiguous and should be used like

```
header()
```

or

```
header(const package_msgs::header<#0> &)
```

Does this mean this header can't be instantiated ? The writer doesn't give support so can't ask. Thanks.

Code sample:

```
void  callback_BB_Twist(amigo_msgs::arm_links msgs_ls_t)
```

Error by Eclipse

```
Description
'amigo_msgs::arm_links' is ambiguous '
Candidates are:
arm_links()
arm_links(const amigo_msgs::arm_links<#0> &)
```

Compiler error:

```
error: ‘amigo_msgs::arm_links’ is not a type
```

A full minimal example:

```
#include "amigo_msgs/arm_links.h"
class ImageP
{
    void callbackBB(amigo_msgs::armlinks msgs_x)
    {
    }
    ImageP(ros::nodehandle* n)
    {
         ls_sub = n->subscribe("<topic>", &ImageP::callbackBB, this);
    }
    void run()
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"imagedo");
    ros::Rate loop_rate(30);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        imagep.run();
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep;
     }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173345/ambiguous-use-of-header-file/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-11**:
That doesn't make much sense. Can you include the code sample you're trying to compile and the exact compiler output?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-11**:
I edited the question. Hope you can make some sense out of it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-11**:
Your include

```
#include "amigo_msgs::arm_links"
```

doesn't look right at all. Is that a typo?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-12**:
Yes, that was a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what Eclipse is trying to tell you. I suspect it is confused.

The underlying error here seems to be that `amigo_msgs::arm_links` isn't a type. Perhaps you forgot to include the appropriate header file?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-11**:
No, I didn't forget to include the header file. That's why it's confusing me as well.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-11**:
Please give a minimal, but complete example of what you are trying to compile.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-11**:
How can I post that best ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-11**:
Edit you original question to provide further information.